# SwiftUI dependent toggle in a conditional view is updated when the view re-appears, instead of when it disappears?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `Toggle` that is dependently-toggled by a parent `Toggle`, and backed by an `@ObservableObject` data model. When the parent toggle is enabled, the child view should be visible, and when the parent toggle becomes disabled, the child view should be removed and the child toggle set to disabled also.

Functionally, my implementation seems to work, and the backing data for the child toggle is updated when the parent toggle is changed, but the child toggle *visually* toggles off when its view re-appears instead, leading to this effect:

[image: Video recording of the problem.]

Note how the child toggle doesn't visually disable until the view re-appears. Here is the view containing the toggles (used by both the parent toggle and the child toggle):

```swift
struct PreferenceBooleanView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: PreferenceModel
    
    var body: some View {
        let booleanBinding = Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                if case .boolean(let value) = model.preference.currentValue {
                    return value
                }
                fatalError("Non-boolean `PreferenceValue` being exposed to `PreferenceBooleanView`")
            },
            set: { newValue in
                withAnimation {
                    model.preference.currentValue = PreferenceValue.boolean(value: newValue)
                    
                    for var child in self.model.preference.children ?? [] {
                        if let newValueForChild = child.onParentSetValue?[newValue] {
                            child.currentValue = newValueForChild
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        
        Toggle(isOn: booleanBinding) {
            Text(model.preference.displayableLabel)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the parent view containing the parent control and the child control:

```swift
struct PreferenceWithChildrenView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: PreferenceModel
    var childPreferences: [PreferenceModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    PreferenceBooleanView(for: model)
                }
                ForEach(childPreferences) { childPreferenceModel in
                    Section {
                        if model.preference.currentValue == childPreferenceModel.preference.parentDisplayCondition {
                            PreferenceBooleanView(for: childPreferenceModel)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle(model.preference.title!)
    }
}
```

What can I do to cause SwiftUI to appropriately re-render the toggle's state when the backing data is actually updated?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - something I can directly copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question to include your `PreferenceModel`. It seems likely that this isn't where your problem lies

Comment: that should be this *IS* where your problem lies - Messing around with `Binding` and having nested observable objects is indicative of a problem

Comment: You compute data and execute logic in views.  But you are using a Model already. So, you could refactor your model such, that it is the sole thing that computes the logic ensuring all invariance rules and publishes the _view_state_. This view state represents the rendered state of your views. In your example this state would be quite simple: `struct ViewState { var parent: Bool, var child: Bool? }`. Getting the animation right, should be easier then.